# How to combine and sum values from duplicate rows in greenDAO (similar to sum and group by in sql)?

Tags: java, android, orm, greendao

I have created a table and it contains values which have repetition as shown below:

```
id     name   mileage
1021  toyota   534
1021  toyota   783
1022  mazda    519
1023  nissan   559
```

In SQL I would succesfully execute:

```
SELECT id ,  SUM(mileage) as TotalMileage FROM vehicleTable group By id
```

I would like to know how I can do this using greenDAO. This is my code below

```
public  List<Vehicles> LoadVehicleData() {

    List<VehicleEntity> items = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicleTable ";
    Cursor c = vehicleDao.getDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        VehicleEntity ve = new VehicleEntity(
                c.getLong(0),
                new Date(),
                mileage = c.getInt(2),
                model = c.getString(3)
                // break;
        );
        items.add(ve);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GreenDAO is useful to work with entities, but for such query I think it would be better to work directly with SQLite, without the intermediation of greenDAO.

[Here](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/164) you can see it explained by the owners.